# How do I fix windows error 0xc000021a

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, bsod, acer-aspire

My PC displays the error 0xc000021a when booting then restarts to recovery mode.
I could not find any of my restore points so I booted into safe mode and disable signature drivers but it still displayed the error.
I also got easy recovery essentials but it says my hard drive does not have a valid windows installation
I found a possible solution on you-tube and created a boot-able windows8 CD with my 8GB pen drive and i did exactly what was done in the you-tube video but i got this error [cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJgBs.jpg)
I don't want to loose any of my apps and files. I'll appreciate the help of any one who has experienced the same problem.

here are my log files:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p87cjj0votp3a5x/AAAQ0N5tFXFqXXc7dlfjdi56a?dl=0

hope it helps.

PC specs:
*Acer E1-532p
*Windows 8.1pro

Comment: 'easy recovery essential' is vaporware, I hope you didn't pay for it, cause it doesn't do anything WinRE cannot do.  The log file will indicate the reason the command failed

Comment: i have updated the question with a link of my log files. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could try "Automatic Repair" (Troubleshoot -> Advanced Options -> StartUp Repair) using installation DVD/USB to see if it can fix damaged system files.

Alternatively you could use on command line: offline "sfc" (system file check) when booted from installation/recovery DVD/USB. Offline means you have to specify Windows drive and System drive using command parameters (see exact syntax from command help - "sfc /?").

Boot files are intact so the error should be in a system file loaded by winload.exe.

Second error suggests that there is little free space on Windows partition. Either save some user files (or whole directories) to USB or move to another partition. Later you can copy back the files. 3-4 GB free space on Windows partition should be enough for repair operation, IMHO.

Comment: I used sfc but it was unable to fix the corrupt files. I have updaetd the question with a link to my log files. Hope it helps.

Comment: If sfc cannot fix corrupted system files, try another iteration with dism to update system store(on disk) and then again sfc. sfc compares files from store with system files and copies over if needed. You need internet connection so dism can get Windows 8.1 files from Windows Update site, else specify source is on Windows 8.1 USB.

Comment: Eventually check this thread "https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/how-to-repair-corrupt-system-files-from-a/329649e1-112f-44b9-bfd4-d1be00a77fc1"